# selectpicker doesnt show data after choosing email

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hope somebody could help me. As I am really  new to php and mysql. Here is my code-

https://www.codepile.net/pile/bmwgqlmd

https://www.codepile.net/pile/W3N7DjP1

The problem is-when I choose email from selectpicker it doesnt connect  to the table and doesnt show selected data.
Can anyone help figure it out how to connect them so it shows selected data?
Thanks.